# Liferay 6.1 Theme - look and feel

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

I have liferay-look-and-feel.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE look-and-feel PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Look and Feel 6.1.0//EN"
"http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-look-and-feel_6_1_0.dtd">

<look-and-feel>
    <compatibility>
       <version>6.1.10+</version>
    </compatibility>
    <theme id="sample-theme" name="Sample Theme">
       <settings>
         <setting key="portlet-setup-show-borders-default" value="false" />
       </settings>
    </theme>
</look-and-feel>
```

I use maven to build my project and build success

But when I open localhost in Eclipse I see:

```
[ThemeLocalServiceImpl:149] No theme found for specified theme id sample_WAR_sampletheme. Returning the default theme.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: If redeployment doesn't work then change the theme `id` to `id="sample"` or `id="sampletheme"` and then redeploy and check. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the property `antiJarLocking` and set `antiResourceLocking` to false in **Liferay-6.1.10/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/sample_WAR_sampletheme/META-INF/context.xml**.
[Read more here](https://www.themeray.com/blog/-/blogs/no-theme-found-for-specified-theme-id-%E2%80%A6-returning-the-default-theme?_33_redirect=https://www.themeray.com/blog?p_p_id=33&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1).

Comment: This is to only possible solution that will be effective. All of the other once are just trying to lay the software but are not working. I did it in this way and for now I did not have any problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of antiResourceLocking in tomcat 7.

Please check out the blog: [No theme found for specified theme id … Returning the default theme](https://www.themeray.com/blog/-/blogs/no-theme-found-for-specified-theme-id-...-the-default-theme)